# Trying to read data from multiple tfrecord files

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a folder of .tfrecords files that I would like to read into my network. However, I am having a lot of trouble reading more than one tfrecords file at a time.

All my tfrecords files are stored in the the `path_to_folders` list. All my feature names are correct as well.

My code looks like this:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for folder in path_to_folders:

        try:
            no_grasps = int(len(os.listdir(folder)) / 5)

            feature_name_images = os.path.basename(folder) + '_images'
            feature_name_csv = os.path.basename(folder) + '_csv'

            data_path = os.path.join(path_to_data, os.path.basename(folder) + '.tfrecords')

            feature = {feature_name_images: tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                       feature_name_csv: tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
                       }

            filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path], num_epochs=1)

            reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

            _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

            features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)

            image_out = tf.decode_raw(features[feature_name_images], tf.float32)
            csv_out = tf.decode_raw(features[feature_name_csv], tf.float32)

            image_out_reshaped = tf.reshape(image_out, [no_grasps, 200, 200, 3])
            csv_out_reshaped = tf.reshape(csv_out, [no_grasps, 6])

            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

            # Create a coordinator and run all QueueRunner objects
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

            # image_dataset, csv_dataset = sess.run([image_out_reshaped, csv_out_reshaped])
            image_dataset = sess.run(image_out_reshaped)

            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)

            print(image_dataset.shape, type(image_dataset))

            time.sleep(2)

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('epoch limit reached')
```

After the first iteration of reading is done (first tfrecords file successfully read) then rest of them tell me that my epoch limit is reached with the warning:

```
OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_2_input_producer_1' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: ReaderReadV2_1 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordReaderV2_1, input_producer_1)]]
```

I really don't understand why this is the case and was wondering if anyone could help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Can you separate the graph construction and graph execution, you are creating a graph inside a loop, which adds same nodes again and again.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do it? I am curious as well. As far as I could follow from examples you would just put all the names of the TFRecord files into the [data_path] list, and the functions run on all the files. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving coord.request_stop() out of your main try block and adding a 'finally' block to your try, like so :

```
    try:
        ...
        #coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)

        print(image_dataset.shape, type(image_dataset))

        #time.sleep(2)

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print('epoch limit reached')
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()
```

You might also want to try moving some of the code outside of the for loop, you can set up a lot of the graph structure elsewhere, for example putting your tf.train.Coordinator() and  tf.train.start_queue_runners ahead of the for loop might be more manageable